# How can I change the exception messages in Vs2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

For a bit of a joke (about 6 months ago), I changed the exceptions file on a colleagues PC so that when a `NullReferenceException` was thrown, he would get a funny Trouble Shooting Tip with a reference to him - We have a joke about him chopping up in his basement...

After forgetting about this, and now 6 months on, this error has arisen, whilst yes it's funny, it also needs to be fixed and changed back.

Any ideas how I'd change it back? Or what file it should be? All my googling seems to point to File Exceptions..

(For that wondering how it looked...)[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file containing the custom troubleshooting tips for VS2012 is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ExceptionAssistantContent\1033\DefaultContent.xml
```

This is what the `NullReferenceException` block should look like:

```
<Exception>
    <Type>System.NullReferenceException</Type>
    <Tip HelpID="EHNullReference">
        <Description>Use the "new" keyword to create an object instance.</Description>
    </Tip>
</Exception>
<Exception>
    <Type>System.NullReferenceException</Type>
    <Tip HelpID="EHNullReference">
    <Description>Check to determine if the object is null before calling the method.</Description>
    </Tip>
</Exception>
```

Kudos for the prank, I'll have to remember that one!

Comment: Cheers! It's even better if you forget for 6+ months!